# I want to upload image and after submit a form, I get this error

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 6

error

```
 The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF80B.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.
```

code

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));
    auth()->user()->article()->create(array_merge($request->all() , [ 'images' => $imagesUrl]));
    return redirect(route('articles.index'));
}
```

Upload Image function

```
protected function uploadImages($file)
{
    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/";
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file = $file->move(public_path($imagePath) , $filename);

    $sizes = ["300" , "600" , "900"];
    $url['images'] = $this->resize($file->getRealPath() , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename);
    $url['thumb'] = $url['images'][$sizes[0]];

    return $url;
}
```

Resize image function

```
private function resize($path , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename)
{
    $images['original'] = $imagePath . $filename;
    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $images[$size] = $imagePath . "{$size}_" . $filename;

        Image::make($path)->resize($size, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path($images[$size]));
    }

    return $images;
}
```

I want to upload image and after submit a form, I get this error.

The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF80B.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.

how can solve this error?